# Работа функций пользователя

Tags: c++

я написал функцию, которая создает двумерный динамический массив, а затем заполняет его нулями. Но при выводе его на экран там не нули. Что сделано неправильно? создаваемый массив является частью структуры struct. size - это некая константа.

```
void din (Struct *struct) {
   struct->mas = new int*[struct->size];
   for (int i=0; i < struct->size; i++) {
        struct->mas[i] = new int[struct->size];
    }
   for (int i=0; i <  struct->size; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < struct->size; j++) {
            struct->mas[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
   for (int i=0; i <  struct->size; cout << endl, i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < struct->size; j++) {
            printf ("%3d ", struct->mas);
        }
   }

}
```

код представлен [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=77)

Comment: приведите весь код - регистрироваться на этом сайте ради вашего вопроса,признаться, нет желания

Comment: @DreamChild, здесь весь код функции, а в результате я получаю матрицу заполненную не нулями, а "5890226". Т.е матрица формируется, но заполняется не 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void din (Struct *struct) {
   struct->mas = new int*[struct->size];
   for (int i=0; i < struct->size; i++) {
        struct->mas[i] = new int[struct->size];
    }
   for (int i=0; i <  struct->size; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < struct->size; j++) {
            struct->mas[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
   for (int i=0; i <  struct->size; cout << endl, i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < struct->size; j++) {
            printf ("%3d ", struct->mas[i][j]);
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: аааа, спасибо)

Comment: вместо того, чтоб закрывать вопрос, лучше бы ответ приняли - он, судя по всему, вас устроил